# Is there a way in Bookdown to make a newpage appear or dissapear based on latex code?

Tags: r, bookdown

I am wondering in Bookdown if there is a way to toggle `\newpage` without having to resort to putting it inside of a `r` coding chunk. Is there a way to do it within the latex portion of bookdown? Almost like writing an if then statement in tex.

Comment: I‘m sure there is a way but it’s probably more complex than using control flow in R. What are you trying to do?